# Issues getting Netty sample "HttpUploadServer" to read HTTP PUT data, works fine with HTTP POST

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to get the sample Netty HttpUploadServer to receive an uploaded file via HTTP PUT, code found here:
   https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/upload/HttpUploadServerHandler.java

To test an HTTP POST file upload, I use this curl command:

```
curl -F "myfile=@testfile.txt" http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

To test an HTTP PUT file upload, I use this curl command:

```
curl -T "testfile.txt" http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

I commented out the writeMenu and return as i'm using curl and not a web browser. Using curl to POST, everything seems to work fine, however with PUT I am not getting any data in readHttpDataAllRecieve (HttpUploadServerhandler):

```
private void readHttpDataAllReceive(Channel channel) {
    List<InterfaceHttpData> datas = null;
    try {
        datas = decoder.getBodyHttpDatas();
        System.out.println("size " + datas.size());
    } catch (NotEnoughDataDecoderException e1) {
        // Should not be!
        e1.printStackTrace();
        responseContent.append(e1.getMessage());
        writeResponse(channel);
        Channels.close(channel);
        return;
    }
    for (InterfaceHttpData data: datas) {
        writeHttpData(data);
    }
    responseContent.append("\r\n\r\nEND OF CONTENT AT FINAL END\r\n");
}
```

datas = decoder.getBodyHttpDatas(); datas always has a 0 size with PUT, but not with POST.

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a CURL expert but maybe CURL is just sending the file "as is" when you PUT rather than  as multipart MIME when you POST.

The content type for a PUT is typically the type of the file; e.g. text/xml.  For a post, it is `multipart/form-data`

`HttpPostRequestDecoder` read and decodes multipart MIME.  See comments at https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpPostRequestDecoder.java#L187

The end result is that for PUT from CURL check if you can change the content type of `multi-part/formdata`. However, this is not efficient because of MIME encoding.

I think a better option is to just handle the uploaded data. Basically, when you get the initial HTTP request, open a file.  As you receive each chunk, write it to the file.  On the last chunk, close the file.

I wrote something a while ago. See https://github.com/chililog/chililog-server/blob/master/src/main/java/org/chililog/server/workbench/ApiRequestHandler.java#L133

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks Veebs, your code on github was very helpful, I ended up creating a custom handler.